# How to fix This Seam in Fork

Tags: modeling

I have this weird seam in my fork that I'm making. It wouldn't be such a big problem but it seems to interfere with the shader and causes a weird seam. I found out there was faces underneath the topology, so i tried removing them with a small amount of success. Here are the pictures,
[image: Fork][image: Fork 2]

I tried smoothing it in sculpting but it makes it much worse. I also tried merging any double vertices, no success. I cannot even select the edge loop. I think it occurred when I subdivided? But by the time I noticed, it was too late to undo the subdivision. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: have you checked the normals? maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your topology has many errors:

- red circle: you have 5 edges come from a single vertex
- green circle: you have 3 edges come from a single vertex

You need to have only quads (A square or rectangular polygon is referred to as a quad or quadrilateral polygon, and is a four-sided polygon. It has exactly 4 vertices at the corners connected by 4 edges) for best shading results.

How to fix it?

Edit your topology to have only quads:

- merge the vertex in orange circles. Select the vertices and press <kbd>M</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> in version 2.79 or older)
- remove the vertex in the yellow circle
- continue fixing the topology to have only quads

[image]

here's a good topology for a fork (source here: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/fork-metal-3d-model-1360722)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix it. I'll use this info to help me in my future projects as well, thanks!

Comment: so please select my answer as "selected". thanks

Comment: My bad, I forgot to click it haha.